# Failed to display the data in function

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, list, function

[the output in red rectangular is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpOTa.png)

[This is the function that I make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H99PC.png)

this is code in another class that I want to pick some data to display in my picture 1 (summary.PrintAll() function)

```js
synchronized public void allocateBus(Data d) {
        TicketCounter T = (TicketCounter) (Thread.currentThread());

        ArrayList<Group> GROUP_A = new ArrayList<Group>();
        ArrayList<Group> GROUP_C = new ArrayList<Group>();

        while (d.getSeat() != 0) {
            if ("A".equals(d.getDestination())) {
                if (BUSA.size() == 0 || BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat() == 0) {
                    BUSA.add(new Bus("A" + BUSA.size()));
                }
                if (d.getSeat() <= BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat()) {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), d.getSeat(), BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getName());

                    BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).Bookingseat(d.getSeat());
                    d.finishedBooking(d.getSeat());

                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat(), BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getName());
                    d.finishedBooking(BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                    BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).Bookingseat(BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                }
            } else {
                if (BUSC.size() == 0 || BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat() == 0) {
                    BUSC.add(new Bus("C" + BUSC.size()));
                }
                if (d.getSeat() <= BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat()) {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), d.getSeat(), BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getName());
                    
                    //GROUP_C.add(new Group(BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getName(), d.getName(), d.getSeat(), d.getDestination()));
                    
                    BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).Bookingseat(d.getSeat());
                    d.finishedBooking(d.getSeat());
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat(), BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getName());
                    d.finishedBooking(BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                    BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).Bookingseat(BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: without having your whole code we cant run it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @coderoftheday this is all of my code https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UJo7u1NmTaq4x1ZT-nOoPcI4UQJS9Orq?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

class BusLine {

    private String destination;
    protected static int max_seat, checkpoint;

    private ArrayList<Bus> BUSA = new ArrayList<Bus>();
    private ArrayList<Bus> BUSC = new ArrayList<Bus>();

    public BusLine(int ms, int cp, String d) {
        max_seat = ms;
        checkpoint = cp;
        destination = d;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void printAirportCheckpoint() {
        TicketCounter T = (TicketCounter) (Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.printf("%s >> %d airport-bound buses have been allocated.\n", T.getName(), BUSA.size());
    }

    public void printCityCheckpoint() {
        TicketCounter T = (TicketCounter) (Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.printf("%s >> %d city-bound buses have been allocated.\n", T.getName(), BUSC.size());
    }

    synchronized public void allocateBus(Data d) {
        TicketCounter T = (TicketCounter) (Thread.currentThread());

        ArrayList<Group> GROUP_A = new ArrayList<Group>();
        ArrayList<Group> GROUP_C = new ArrayList<Group>();

        while (d.getSeat() != 0) {
            if ("A".equals(d.getDestination())) {
                if (BUSA.size() == 0 || BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat() == 0) {
                    BUSA.add(new Bus("A" + BUSA.size()));
                }
                if (d.getSeat() <= BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat()) {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), d.getSeat(), BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getName());

                    BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).Bookingseat(d.getSeat());
                    d.finishedBooking(d.getSeat());

                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat(), BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getName());
                    d.finishedBooking(BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                    BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).Bookingseat(BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                }
            } else {
                if (BUSC.size() == 0 || BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat() == 0) {
                    BUSC.add(new Bus("C" + BUSC.size()));
                }
                if (d.getSeat() <= BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat()) {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), d.getSeat(), BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getName());
                    
                    //GROUP_C.add(new Group(BUSA.get(BUSA.size() - 1).getName(), d.getName(), d.getSeat(), d.getDestination()));
                    
                    BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).Bookingseat(d.getSeat());
                    d.finishedBooking(d.getSeat());
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%s >> Transaction %2d : %-20s(%2d seats) bus %s\n", T.getName(), d.getTransaction(), d.getName(), BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat(), BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getName());
                    d.finishedBooking(BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                    BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).Bookingseat(BUSC.get(BUSC.size() - 1).getAvailableSeat());
                }
            } 
        } 
    } 
}

class BoundBus {

    private String Tourname;
    private int Seat;

    public BoundBus(String TN, int s) {
        Tourname = TN;
        Seat = s;
    }
}

class Group {

    private String busname, name, destination;
    private int seat;

    public Group() {
    }

    public Group(String n, String b, int s, String d) {
        busname = n;
        name = b;
        seat = s;
        destination = d;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getBusname(){
        return busname;
    }
    
    public String getDestination(){
        return destination;
    }
    
    public int getSeat(){
        return seat;
    }
        
    public void printAll() {
        Thread G = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println();
        
        if ("A".equals(destination)) {
            System.out.printf("%s >> ==== Airport Bound ====", G.getName());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s >> %s : ", G.getName(), busname);
            System.out.printf("%-20s(%2d seats)", name, seat);
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s >> ==== City Bound ====", G.getName());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s >> %s : ", G.getName(), busname);
            System.out.printf("%-20s(%2d seats)", name, seat);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class Bus {

    private String Busname, group_name;
    private int availableseat, seat;

    public int getAvailableSeat() {
        return availableseat;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Busname;
    }

    public void Bookingseat(int s) {
        availableseat -= s;
    }

    public Bus(String n) {
        availableseat = BusLine.max_seat;
        Busname = n;
    }

    public Bus(String n, int s) {
        group_name = n;
        seat = s;
    }
    
    public Bus(String n, String gn ,int s){
        Busname = n;
        group_name = gn;
        availableseat = s;
    }
    
}

class Data {

    private String name, destination;
    private int seat, transaction, count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void finishedBooking(int s) {
        seat -= s;
    }

    public Data(int t, String n, int s, String d) {
        transaction = t;
        name = n;
        seat = s;
        destination = d;
    }
}

class TicketCounter extends Thread {

    ArrayList<Data> transaction;
    BusLine Airport, City;
    private int count;
    private CyclicBarrier cfinish;

    public void setCyclicBarrier(CyclicBarrier f) {
        cfinish = f;
    }

    public TicketCounter(String n, ArrayList<Data> d, BusLine a, BusLine c) {
        super(n);
        transaction = d;
        Airport = a;
        City = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < transaction.size(); i++) {
            if (transaction.get(i).getTransaction() == BusLine.checkpoint) {
                try {
                    cfinish.await();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                Airport.printAirportCheckpoint();
                City.printCityCheckpoint();
            }
            if ("A".equals(transaction.get(i).getDestination())) {
                //System.out.printf("1. %s\n",transaction.get(i).getDestination());
                Airport.allocateBus(transaction.get(i));
                /*if (transaction.get(i).getSeat() > BusLine.max_seat) {
                    i--;
                }*/
            } else {
                //System.out.printf("2. %s\n",transaction.get(i).getDestination());
                City.allocateBus(transaction.get(i));
                /*if (transaction.get(i).getSeat() > BusLine.max_seat) {
                    i--;
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
}

class Userinput {

    private int MAX_SEAT, CHECK_POINT;

    private ArrayList<Data> DATA1 = new ArrayList<Data>();
    private ArrayList<Data> DATA2 = new ArrayList<Data>();
    private ArrayList<Data> DATA3 = new ArrayList<Data>();

    public Userinput() {
    }

    public int getMaxseat() {
        return MAX_SEAT;
    }

    public int getCheckpoint() {
        return CHECK_POINT;
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getDATA1() {
        return DATA1;
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getDATA2() {
        return DATA2;
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getDATA3() {
        return DATA3;
    }

    public void input() {

        String infile[] = {"T1.txt", "T2.txt", "T3.txt"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            boolean opensuccess = false;
            while (!opensuccess) {
                try ( Scanner scanfile = new Scanner(new File(infile[i]));) {
                    while (scanfile.hasNext()) {

                        opensuccess = true;
                        String line = scanfile.nextLine();
                        String[] buf = line.split(",");
                        int transaction = Integer.parseInt(buf[0].trim());
                        String name = buf[1].trim();
                        int seat = Integer.parseInt(buf[2].trim());
                        String destination = buf[3].trim();
                        Data d = new Data(transaction, name, seat, destination);
                        switch (i) {
                            case 0:
                                DATA1.add(d);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                DATA2.add(d);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                DATA3.add(d);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter new file name : ");
                    infile[i] = scan.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Simulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
/*
        Thread Th = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.printf("%s >> Enter max seats = ", Th.getName());
        System.out.println();
        int max_seat = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("%s >> Enter checkpoints = ", Th.getName());
        System.out.println();
        int checkpoint = scan.nextInt();
*/
        Userinput U = new Userinput();

        int max_seat = 50;
        int checkpoint = 3;
        
        BusLine Airport = new BusLine(max_seat, checkpoint, "A");
        BusLine City = new BusLine(max_seat, checkpoint, "C");

        U.input();

        TicketCounter[] T = {
            new TicketCounter("T1", U.getDATA1(), Airport, City),
            new TicketCounter("T2", U.getDATA2(), Airport, City),
            new TicketCounter("T3", U.getDATA3(), Airport, City)};

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            T[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                T[i].join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
        
        Group summary = new Group();
        summary.printAll();
        
    }
}
```